# filters in twig call

Tags: symfony, twig

how could I call a function from another function filter another filter?
eg

```
public function getFilters()
     {

         return array (
             'test' => new \ Twig_Filter_Method ($this, 'test'),
             'test1' => new \ Twig_Filter_Method ($this, 'test1', array('is_safe' => array('html')))
         );
     }


public function test($test)
{
    return;
}


public function test1($test)
{
    // how to test call?
}
```

thanks and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

From twig template you can do that like this:

```
{{ 'Some string'|test|test1('argument')}}
```

Inside twig extension class you can call `test` function like regular php object function:

```
public function test1($test)
{
    // your code
    $testResult = $this->test($test);
}
```